# Largest Negative Number after Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Good day,

I would like to group-by **contract number** & find the maximum negative number. I was thinking of using the following code.

```
idx = data.groupby(['contract'])['RenVsRec'].max([n for n in data.RenVsRec if n<0])
```

Comment: Please create a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: go ahead. Give it a try.

Comment: What is a maximum negative number? The largest number below 0? Or the largest by magnitude? That would just be, the smallest number.

Answer (score 2):

First filter by [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) or [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then aggregate `max`:

```
df = data.query('RenVsRec < 0').groupby('contract')['RenVsRec'].max()
#alternative
#df = data[data['RenVsRec'] < 0].groupby('contract')['RenVsRec'].max()
```

**Sample**:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'RenVsRec':[-5,-3,6,-9,2,-4],
                   'contract':list('aaabbb'),
                   'col':range(6)})

print (data)

   RenVsRec  col contract
0        -5    0        a
1        -3    1        a
2         6    2        a
3        -9    3        b
4         2    4        b
5        -4    5        b

df = data.query('RenVsRec < 0').groupby('contract')['RenVsRec'].max()
print (df)
contract
a   -3
b   -4
Name: RenVsRec, dtype: int64
```

If want all columns use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) for indices by max negative and select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = data.loc[data[data['RenVsRec'] < 0].groupby('contract')['RenVsRec'].idxmax()]
```

Or filtering + [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by last row by `contract`:

```
df = (data.query('RenVsRec < 0')
          .sort_values(['contract', 'RenVsRec'])
          .drop_duplicates('contract', keep='last'))
```

---

```
print (df)
   RenVsRec  col contract
1        -3    1        a
5        -4    5        b
```